# Python - Write an array to csv / txt and then read

Tags: python, csv, text

So if I have the following code:

```
database = []
Name = input("What's the members name?")
MT = input("What membership type?")
DOB = input("What is the member DOB?")
DJ = (now.day ,"/" , now.month, "/", now.year)
year1 = int(now.year)
month1 = int(now.month)
day1 = int(now.day)
ry = int(year1 + 1)
rm = month1
rd = day1
renewal = (day1, month1, year1 + 1)
details = ["Name:",  Name, "Membership Type:", MT, "Date of Birth:", DOB, "Date Joined:", DJ,"Renewal Date:", renewal, "Renewal Year:", ry]
database.append(details)
menu()
```

How would I go about saving (database) to a text file / csv file to be read later.
I have tried pickle but the issue is I need to be able to get each part of the array seperate.
For example if I type:

```
print(database[1])
```

I will return all Names stored as "Name", however if I were to write the file using pickle when I bring it back in then

```
print (database[1])
```

now shows the entirety of the second user added. I need to be able to save (database) and have it in the same format when read back in.
Expected output using JSON or Pickle(assuming the first user inputted name as "Jeff" and second inputted name as "John")

```
print (database[1])

Jeff
John
```

Actual output:

```
["Name:",  John, "Membership Type:", MT, "Date of Birth:", DOB, "Date Joined:", DJ,"Renewal Date:", renewal, "Renewal Year:", ry]
```

- Sorry for the bad explanation I'm new to python.

Comment: you have many choices. You could dump your dict using JSON, or use DictWriter to dump as csv.

Comment: I tried this but had the same issue I had with pickle? Any advice

Comment: I don't understand what's your problem is exactly. Can you post the output (when reading back) and your expected output?

Comment: Updated the post with expected and actual

Comment: @Jonathan. Why would the expected output print **two** names? At the moment, `database` is a *list of lists*, so to get the second element of the first record, you should do `print(database[0][1])` - and that would output `John`.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are creating an array of records. Try accessing the data in this way:

```
print(database[0][1])    #[0] for the first record, [1] for second item
print(database[1][1])    #second user, second item
```